# Using firebase smart config url in an angular app

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, angularfire2

I'm working on an angular/firebase app.
I generated it via '@angular/cli' and ng new.

It will be hosted on firebase.
I installed 'angularfire2'.
I followed the [angularfire2 setup](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md).
I managed the dev server in 'package.json' via '"start": "ng build --watch | firebase serve",'.

In this configuration, is it possible to initialize firebase via the smart URL '/__/firebase/init.json'.

Answer (score 0):

AngularFire does not support initialization with the smart config url.